# Salesforce Mobile App + OpenCTI

Tags: mobile, opencti

Can Salesforce Mobile application integrate with Opencti framework? Can a 3rd party vendor add their CTI controls to the Salesforce Mobile application.

Currently, you can add your CTI related functionality to the Salesforce Browser window, as Iframe (opencti) integration.

Can this be extended to the Mobile app also? If so, how?
Thanks,
Siva

Comment: Have you checked out [Force.com Canvas](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Canvas)?

Answer (score 1):

At this moment (Winter '14) there is no integration between the salesforce mobile or salesforce1 applications with Open CTI. This requires the salesforce mobile applications to support global or application level components/actions.

You may have to wait until Dreamforce (Winter '15) this year for an update :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly add the ability to make calls with a custom action to route through your PBX or cloud PBX.

In addition, you can get custom screen pops on your phone. I have done this with a custom app for iphone that pulls the info from Salesforce. Hope this helps!

Comment: Using open cti this can be done or any some other way? Can you explain more on it?