# How to add RingCentral Click-to-Call to Salesforce iOS mobile app?

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, ios, opencti

I'd like to extend the Salesforce mobile app with click-to-call / click-to-dial capabilities using the RingCentral mobile app so I can place calls using RingCentral instead of the native dialer. I'd like to do this on the Contacts object where a phone number is present.

RingCentral has a Salesforce Open CTI integration. Can this, or another, approach be used to implement click-to-call?

I'd also like this to work for the [Salesforce Developer Account](https://developer.salesforce.com/).

The following post has a 2014 answer indicating no OpenCTI support in the Salesforce mobile app, but a possibility via a custom action, but without an example.

[Salesforce Mobile App + OpenCTI](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25637/salesforce-mobile-app-opencti)

Answer (score 1):

RingCentral click-to-call can be added using the RingCentral for Salesforce Integration:

- https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EORsjUAH

The following Admin Guide shows how to install the integration:

- https://netstorage.ringcentral.com/guides/sfdc_lightning_admin_guide_v6.pdf

Here is a quick overview with some modifications that I found useful. Note, this also works for Android.

## 1. Install RingCentral for Salesforce

Install the managed package from your Salesforce console. I followed instructions similar to the following:

- https://support.ringcentral.com/s/article/10676-ringcentral-salesforce-app-install

## 2. Configure Salesforce

This section covers configuring Salesforce. SSee more here:

- https://support.ringcentral.com/s/article/10687-ringCentral-salesforce-app-add-call-sms-options
- Page 49 in the RingCentral for Salesforce v6 Admin Guide PDF

### 2.1 Create Actions

You can create your own actions or use the actions that come with the integration. I chose to create my own so I could set the Label that appears in the Salesforce mobile app. If you want to use the out of the box actions, you can skip this step.

> Note: creating your own actions gives you additional flexibility like choosing your own labels (display names) in the mobile app. I like using "RingCentral Call" and "RingCentral SMS".

Go to the Salesforce Setup Console Object Manager and perform the following for each object you want to add Click-to-Call to, for example, Contacts and Accounts.

1. Click Object, e.g. Accounts
2. Click "Buttons, Links, and Actions"

For Click to Call, add a New Action:

1. Click "New Action"
2. Set Action Type to "Custom Visualforce"
3. Set Visualforce page to `Phone Numbers Account [rcsfl__Phone_Numbers_Account]` in select drop down
4. Set Label to your choosing, e.g. "RingCentral Call"

For Click to SMS, add a New Action:

1. Click "New Action"
2. Set Action Type to "Custom Visualforce"
3. Set Visualforce page to `Phone Numbers Account [rcsfl__Phone_Numbers_Account]` in select drop down
4. Set Label to your choosing, e.g. "RingCentral Call"

### 2.2 Adding Buttons to Objects (Mobile & Lightning)

> Note: there can be a lot of actions per object. The Salesforce mobile app may only display the top 3 in addition to a "More" button. If you use RingCentral a lot, add the buttons in the top 3.

For each object:

1. Click "Page Layout"
2. In the resulting list edit "{Object} Layout", e.g. "Account Layout" or "Contact Layout".
3. In the top component bar click "Mobile & Lightning Actions"
4. In the section "Salesforce Mobile and Lightning - Experience Actions", if you see a text message with a link "override the predefined actions" click it.
5. Drag and drop the button to "Salesforce Mobile and Lightning -Experience Actions". I added "RingCentral Call" and "RingCentral SMS" to the front of the list so they are easy to find.

## 3. Install the RingCentral iOS Mobile App

1. [Install and login to the RingCentral Phone app here](https://www.ringcentral.com/apps/rc-app)

## 4. Use the Salesforce iOS Mobile App

1. Install and login to the Salesforce iOS Mobile App.
2. Go to the Contact or Account object with a phone number.
3. You should see the "RingCentral Call" and "RingCentral SMS" buttons right away. If you don't, click "More" and scan for them in the list.
4. Click "RingCentral Call" and you will be navigated to the RingCentral Phone app to make an outgoing call.

See more here:

- https://support.ringcentral.com/s/article/8995

## Salesforce Developer Account

This approach has been verified to work with a Salesforce developer account.